# NetBeans, Conectar a una Base de datos

Tags: mysql, netbeans

Hola estoy desarrollando un programa básico que consiste en conectar netbeans a una base de datos vía mysql, el problema es que no se que hacer, se supone que esta base de datos no sólo debe estar en una máquina si no en varias ¿deberán estar conectadas en Red las máquinas? O ¿hay alguna manera de acceder por WIFI?

¿QUÉ ME RECOMIENDAN?

Comment: Hola David, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español, te invito a que conozcas como funciona la comunidad visitando esta [presentación](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). También te recomiendo que visites el tema [cómo elaboro una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por último, te recomiendo que aclares un poco tus conceptos, por ejemplo cuando una red  WiFi es como cualquier otra red, solo que la conexión es inalámbrica y no cableada. Es decir, te conectas a la red por cualquiera de los dos medios. Es lo mismo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puedes usar JDBC con el driver de MySQL. Para crear la base de datos  puedes usar mysql workbench, lo puedes administrar en la misma máquina.

Answer (score 3):

> ¿Cómo conectar NetBeans a una base de datos MySQL utilizando Java?

Hay 2 maneras con NetBeans, pero para ambas necesitarás el driver MySQL-[JDBC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity).

- Con el asistente automático (siguiente imagen).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Descargándolo de la [página oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) e importándolo en tu proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ¿Dónde debe estar ubicada mi base de datos?

Depende, si la necesitas únicamente para Intranet, en un equipo de tu red `p.e 192.168.1.100` y cuando te conectes accedes a esa dirección, si la necesitas para Internet, con JDBC es más complejo, apenas ningún hosting ofrece soporte para JDBC, deberías de contratar un servidor e instalarlo (mucho más coste, sale más a cuenta PHP-PDO).

> ¿Cómo trabajo/gestiono con MySQL?

Hay muchas alternativas, las 2 más simples y populares son:

- [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/): Entorno web ubicado en el servidor.
- [MySQLWorkbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/): Entorno escritorio para trabajar a nivel local.

Te recomiendo trabajar en MySQLWorkbench y después portarlo al phpMyAdmin.

> ¿Cómo establezco una conexión y realizo consultas?

Tengo una pequeña librería que cumple con esto, [ENLACE](https://github.com/ticdenis/API_DNA/tree/master/JAVA/bases_de_datos)

## Ejemplos de uso

#### tryConnection(argumentos).ping() para configurar la conexión y comprobarla.

```
boolean response = MySQL.tryConnection(url, port, database, user, password).ping();
```

#### insert(consulta, parametros, OnInsert) para realizar una consulta SQL de inserción.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO person VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
String[] params = new String[]{null, "java", "mysql", "22"};

MySQL.insert(query, params, (rowsInserted) -> {
    System.out.println( rowsInserted != 0 ? "INSERT OK" : "INSERT ERROR" );
});
```

#### select(consulta, parametros, OnSelect) para realizar una consulta SQL de obtención.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE age > ?;";
String[] params = new String[]{"17"};

MySQL.select(query, params, (resultSet) -> {
    while (resultSet.next()) { /* Código */ }
    System.out.println( resultSet != null ? "SELECT OK" : "SELECT ERROR" );
});
```